# Is it possible to create a global context available throughout the web application when i receive a message from Azure Service Bus?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azureservicebus

I have a web api application which subscribes to a topic in azure service bus during startup.

When I receive a message from service bus, is it possible to establish a context similar to `HttpContext` that is available across the application methods?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough here to give you any exact direction, but in general, this just involves scopes. If whatever is listening for messages is has a "scoped" lifetime, then you can inject your context directly. If, as is more likely, it has a singleton lifetime, then you must instead inject `IServiceProvider` and retrieve your context via:

```
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();

    // do something with context
}
```

You can only use the context within the scope, so do not try to do something like store it in an instance variable or something.